# do I need to change firebase credentials everytime I added new ruless?

Tags: javascript

I want to minimize my retrieval on data in firebase by index based on the status

I tried to add .indexOn in my rules

is my rules correct?

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "projects": {
        "$projectid": {
            "tracking": {
                    "list": {
                        "$listid": {
                            "tracking": {
                                "lbc": {
                                    ".indexOn": "status"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        }



  }
}
```

my database looks like this
[image: database]

Comment: Hi @Juan De Fed given your screenshot, you are not using `$listid` in any kind.

Comment: sorry. I just realize just now. after the list should be a set of an array like this, my picture lacking the array part

Comment: projects: {
1: {
tracking: {
list: [
firebasegeneradeindex:{
tracking: {
lbc:{ status}
}
}
]

Comment: or my code to retrieve is the error?
ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('PENDING').once("value", function(snapshot) {
      // console.log(snapshot.val());
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          console.log(data.value.tracking);
      });
  });

Comment: Your ref should be referencing to "projects/1/tracking/list/tracking/lbc" then everything should work fine, at least I don't see any mistake

Comment: yes. thanks I think I got it now